# Google App Engine Python: Know if an entity has been 'seen' by a user

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

If you use messaging apps (Whatsapp, BBM, Facebook's Messenger), then you should be familiar with the indication of your messages being 'seen' by your recipient.

I would like to build this feature to my entities.

For example, consider this Entity(ndb.Model):

```
class Entity(ndb.Model):
    title = ndb.StringProperty()
    seen = ndb.BooleanProperty(default = False)

class RenderEntity(BaseHandler):
    #renders entity on a template
    def get(self, entity_id):
        entity = Entity.get_by_id('Entity', entity_id)
        self.render('entity_template.html', entity = entity)
```

Here is the entity_template.html

```
<body>
    {{entity.title}}
    {{entity.seen}}
</body>
```

How do I make it so that: if a particular user sees this entity, then the `seen` property will be set to True?

Comment: What code shows the entity to the user? It's *trivial* to set `seen` to True when you render the message to the destination user. There is really nothing more to it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, please see the updated post. The entity is actually accessible to anyone, but I would like an indication that a particular user (ie. matches a specific 'user_id') has seen it.

Comment: And how do you determine the user id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply [update the `Entity`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities#updating_entities) in your view:

```
class RenderEntity(BaseHandler):
    #renders entity on a template
    def get(self, entity_id):
        entity = Entity.get_by_id('Entity', entity_id)

        # TODO: determine user_id and reciever_user_id
        if user_id == receiver_user_id:
            entity.seen = True
            entity.put()

        self.render('entity_template.html', entity = entity)
```

You did not specify how you determine the `user_id` nor how you know it the recipient, but you can use a simple `if` test once you do have them.

Comment: Ahh yes, the challenge here is setting up a code which 'receives user id' from the user who is currently viewing the entity, which is essentially what I am asking. We can assume that

Comment: @haopei: Then *make that clear in your question*; do you have any kind of user authentication in your application?

Comment: Yes, the user_id of the logged-in user is stored as a hashed cookie :) I think this just answered the question. So, I should retrieve the logged-in user_id from the cookie and match it to the targeted user. Assuming this is the solution, is it inefficient if 1000 people sees the entity, and 1000 matches are performed?

Comment: @haopei: you already loaded the entity, the cookie is already received. Comparing the strings is *not* going to affect your performance here.

Comment: If you are tracking each users view of each document, then you will need to either store the list viewed document ids against the user or list of viewing users against the document.  However storing this detail at the user level or the document level won't scale. You will probably need to create a specific entity that you create that combines the userid and documentid that allows you to quickly check of the current combination has been viewed with a single get.